# how to load a dataset with both tabs and comma in pig

Tags: apache-pig

I am trying to load this into pig but I am having a hard time loading it as five different fields.

My dataset

```
QTM 2009,0.53,0.47,1365900
QTM 2009,0.56,0.54,1246100
QTM 2009,0.6,0.54,1023600
```

If I try loading this using a TextLoader, it reads the row as one field.

I also tried loading it as two fields and then using a STRSPLIT command and then comnbing the two. The problem with that is then it declares it as bytearray by default. I want to be able to perform aggregation.
i used the following command to do that:

```
A = Load 'NYSEB.txt' AS(Symbol:chararray, Detail:chararray);
B = Foreach A GENERATE (STRSPLIT(Symbol, ',',1)), (STRSPLIT(Detail, ',', 
4));
B = Foreach A GENERATE
flatten(STRSPLIT (Symbol, ',',1)),
flatten(STRSPLIT(Detail, ',', 4));
```

Can someone plese help me: I want my fields to be
 (symbol:string, year:string, op:double, cp:double, vol:int)

Answer (score 0):

Load the file into 4 fields with comma as the separator and then use `strsplit` on the first field to get the desired 5 fields.

```
 A = LOAD 'NYSEB.txt' USING PigStorage(',') AS (symbol_year:chararray, op:double, cp:double, vol:int);
 B = FOREACH A GENERATE FLATTEN(STRSPLIT(symbol_year,'\\t',2)) as (symbol:chararray,year:chararray),op,cp,vol; 
 C = FOREACH B GENERATE symbol, year, op, cp, vol;
 DUMP C;
```